# Insert into a vector from a function

Tags: c++, function, sockets, vector, insert

I'm writing code for a router. I've managed to get as far as to send and receive information from clients. What I want to do now, is to make a vector that handles all the incoming packages from the thread I have that receives packages.

I'm using C++ and BOOST.

```
int rawpacket_recv(int s, unsigned char *packet, int length)
{
    int to_recv = 0;

    to_recv = read(s, packet, length);
    //and some error detection
}

void RecvThread(int *socket)
{
    int eth_receiver, eth_socket;

    eth_socket = *socket;

    for(;;)
    {
        unsigned char *eth_buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(1518);

        eth_receiver = rawpacket_recv(eth_socket, eth_buffer, 1518);

        //put eth_buffer into a vector defined in main

        free(eth_buffer);
        usleep(10000);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<unsigned char *> packages;

    int eth0socket;
    char eth0 = "eth0";

    eth0socket = CreateAndBindSocket(ETH_P_ALL, &eth0socket, eth0); //Method from the program that does what it name describes

    boost::thread eth0recvthread(RecvThread, &eth0socket);

    eth0recvthread.interrupt();
    eth0recvthread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I've left some unimportant code out of the snippet, but what I want is for RecvThread to be able to put received packages into this vector so that I can process them in the main method (for now) - presumably working as a mutex/semaphore.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a memory leak waiting to happen, plus a race condition.

Comment: You should try using [libtins](http://libtins.sourceforge.net). Processing raw packets can be a pain.

Comment: Maybe some library providing concurrent data structures could be helpful as well.

Comment: Maybe a queue is better than a vector to handle incoming packets?

Comment: @Jepessen You're probably right. Didn't know that C++ had a queue container since I'm mostly used to C# and Java. I will give the queue container a look through

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE: for future questions, the *IDE* you use is really not relevant to the problem at hand, unless the question is *about* the IDE itself.. :) )

Having said that, the sequence should be:

1. Pass in a reference to the vector to your thread function (and mutex + condition variable.)
2. In the thread function, acquire the mutex, push to the vector and notify on the condition variable.
3. In the main function, in a loop, wait for a notification on the condition variable, and if the vector is not empty, process the entry.
4. Manage memory properly (i.e. use a `vector<unsigned char>` to store the packet rather than a raw buffer, then you don't need to bother with freeing...

Comment: I'm all pretty new to C++ to be honest. By passing a reference you mean that I should include it in the function call? If so how should I do that. I'm pretty new to the idea of pointers and stuff..

Also how do I put a packet of type "unsigned char *" into a vector of type "unsigned char"?

Answer (score 1):

Put the vector in a class, together with its mutex, as well as the memory management. (Which should not be `malloc`, unless there's an existing C API which consumes the allocations)

Comment: Next huge challenge acquired.. I hate working with classes in C++. I have basically no knowledge of how to work with both .h and .cpp files. Do you maybe have the courage to trying to explain how they work?

Comment: @Zeliax: there are dozens of (book) authors who've done that, better than I can do in 600 chars.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks anyway. I'll find something out there on the world wide web ;)

Comment: How do you "put" the vector in a class? Do you want me to create a class with Vector like behavior? Extend the vector class? Or just create a class that handles the vector through functions?

Comment: @Zeliax: Just add a member variable, with type `std::vector< Packet >`. The biggest problem would actually be choosing that type `Packet`.